# Auth::login($user) doesn't create a logged session in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting a user object from database and authenticating it in Laravel using:

```
 Auth::login($laravelUser);
```

When I try to access the homepage, it brings me to the login page as I have used a middleware to allow logged in users to access homepage only. That means the user doesn't get logged in even though when I print the data of logged in user using `Auth::user();`, I can see the complete object.

Comment: Does your custom middleware execute after the StartSession middleware?

Comment: @sisve can you please elaborate, I enable middleware code by using them in controller's constructor like this `$this->middleware('auth');`